# How to implement file explorer for Android without ListView

Tags: android, file, listview, explorer

I'm going to develop my file explorer on Android.

On the most examples and tutorials it is done via ListView.

And my question is:

Is it possible to view files without ListView? May be there are more professional ways to do that.

My file explorer should be simple but fully functional. The features are scrolling, context menu, multi selection support...

Thank you very much.

Comment: what so you mean by without listview how will show content do u have any design to put on which recommendation can be given

Comment: And btw, what do you mean "more professional"? How exactly is ListView not professional?

Comment: "recommendation can be given" more information please...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it any way you want without using ListView:

- You can set up a grid layout and have tiles of icons representing directories and files
- You can make it look like Linux terminal and print everything with simple text
- You can make a 3D environment like in hacker movies from early 90s and visualize your file system as a futuristic city
- You can create a SurfaceView, or an ImageView and draw everything on it using Canvas
- etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to show tiles, icons of directories and files.
I'm looking for the easiest way to do that. But I don't want to have a problem in the future development. For example if I want to add a feature 
but realize that it is impossible because of my wrong choice.
As I understood the ListView is most convenient way. 
Will continue to search good examples.

Comment: There are many ways how you can implement your code and there's no way to know if you will have problems with adding new features in the future. Calculating possible risks and coming up with a scalable design is entirely up to you. That's a very broad topic and I don't think anyone would give you a definitive answer. As far as the grid layout goes, look up grid layout tutorials in google, there's plenty.